# Complex LINQ sorting using Lambda Expressions

Tags: c#, .net, linq, expression-trees

Does anyone have/know of an IQueryable.OrderBy extension that takes an Expression (retrieved, for example, by Reflection)?  I believe the function would look something like this:

```
public static IQueryable<TEntity> OrderBy<TEntity>
    (this IQueryable<TEntity> source, Expression sortExpression)
```

Expression would be assumed to be an `Expression<Func<TEntity, T>>` where TEntity is the same object being sorted on, and T is a type that needs to be determined in order to create the new IQueryable.

I've found many examples of extensions that take a string, including Dynamic Linq, like this:

```
public static IQueryable<TEntity> OrderBy<TEntity>(
    this IQueryable<TEntity> source, string sortExpression)
```

If it's possible to take the string and use Reflection to look up the type from the object in question, it should also be possible to take the Expression, and get the value type which is right there IN the Expression.

---

Following is a detailed explanation of why I'd like to have this, which you may or may not need.

I have a rather large list of complex records to sort.  Because the list is so long, I prefer to have the sorting done on the database side.  To handle more complex properties, I've created Expressions that provide the sorting functionality, like so:

```
if (model.sortExpression == "PlannedValue")
{
    Expression<Func<BDopp, decimal>> sorter = BDopp.PlannedValueSorter;         
    if (model.sortDirection == "DESC")
        opps = opps.OrderByDescending(sorter).AsQueryable();
    else
        opps = opps.OrderBy(sorter).AsQueryable();
}
```

BDOpp.PlannedValueSorter retrieves a static expression from the object which allows sorting to be done without opps are still of type IQueryable:

```
public static Expression<Func<BDopp, decimal>> PlannedValueSorter
    {
        get
        {
            return z => z.BudgetSchedules
                .Where(s => s.Type == 1)
                .Sum(s => s.Value * s.Workshare * z.valueFactor / 100 / 100);
        }
    }
```

Sorting for simple properties is done with Extension methods that use Reflection to build an expression based on the name of the property passed as a string.

This works well, but for the complex types, I still need branching logic, and I'd rather not do that.  What I'd rather do is check for a static property containing the expression, and then simply apply it.  I can get the expression like this:

```
PropertyInfo info = typeof(BDopp).GetProperty(model.sortExpression + "Sorter",
    BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);
Expression expr = (Expression)info.GetValue(null, null);
```

For the PlannedValue property, this gets me the expression sorted in PlannedValueSorter, which I already know works.

---

### Update:

Various digging around has gotten me what I think might be some progress:

```
public static IQueryable<TEntity> OrderBy<TEntity>(this IQueryable<TEntity> source, 
    Expression<Func<TEntity, dynamic>> sortExpression)
    {
        var unary = sortExpression.Body as UnaryExpression;
        Type actualExpressionType = unary.Operand.Type;
```

actualExpressionType is in fact the return type of the Expression (for this particular property, it's decimal).

Unfortunately I'm mostly just working by trial and error, since I haven't yet wrapped my brain around how all this works, so my attempt to update the query like so is not working:

```
        MethodCallExpression resultExp = Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), 
            "OrderBy",
            new Type[] { typeof(TEntity), actualExpressionType },
            source.Expression, sortExpression);
        return source.Provider.CreateQuery<TEntity>(resultExp);
```

It compiles okay, but the following error is thrown at runtime:

> No generic method 'OrderBy' on type 'System.Linq.Queryable' is
>   compatible with the supplied type arguments and arguments. No type
>   arguments should be provided if the method is non-generic.

Comment: Possibly semi-related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15297884/construct-a-linq-groupby-query-using-expression-trees/15300502#15300502

Comment: The normal `OrderBy()` already takes an expression. Why can't you use that?

Comment: Normal OrderBy requires a strongly typed expression, but without setting up a long list of branching conditions, I won't know the type at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it you have an `Expression` and want to order/filter by it. It might surprise you how simple it is:

```
Expression<Func<TEntity, T>> sortExpr = ...; //you already have this
var ordered = myQuery.OrderBy(sortExpr);
```

OrderBy *always* uses an `Expression` so you can directly use it. If you only have a variable of type `Expression` (which points to an object of type `Expression<Func<TEntity, T>>`) and don't know statically what `T` is, you can do this:

```
Expression sortExpr = ...; //you already have this
var ordered = myQuery.OrderBy((dynamic)sortExpr);
```

`dynamic` will figure this out at runtime using reflection. No need to do reflection yourself. All that is needed here is overload resolution (performed by the C# runtime binder).

Comment: I had actually already tried this, and got an error complaining that "Extension methods cannot be dynamically dispatched.  Consider casting the dynamic arguments or calling the extension method without the extension method syntax."  Am I missing a reference, perhaps?

Comment: Ah yes. Use `Queryable.OrderBy(myQuery, (dynamic)sortExpr)`. The fix is to just not use extension method syntax!

Comment: Alas.  Unable to cast the type 'System.Decimal' to type 'System.Object'. LINQ to Entities only supports casting EDM primitive or enumeration types.

Comment: But, that error led me to this answer, which led to the solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9155222/135105

Comment: Hm I feel we haven't gotten to the root of the issue yet (which is always troubling to me) because I don't understand why that error message appeared but I'm glad your problem is solved.

Comment: OK seeing your answer I'd be interested in finding out why mine didn't work. It should. Where did the exception occur? Probably not on the `OrderBy` call. That did go through, right? What was the runtime type of `ordered` (meaning what did `ordered.GetType().FullName` return?)? Maybe my understanding of dynamic runtime binding behavior was not accurate and needs to be corrected.

Comment: I am only guessing here, but I'm thinking the standard OrderBy override simply treats dynamic as object, instead of figuring out what data type the expression actually returns, and then tries to cast that return type to object.  (You're right, the error occurred when I called Count() and the query was actually executed.)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I've got a solution:

```
public static IQueryable<TEntity> OrderBy<TEntity>(
    this IQueryable<TEntity> source, 
    Expression<Func<TEntity, dynamic>> sortExpression, 
    bool descending)
    {
        var unary = sortExpression.Body as UnaryExpression;
        var operand = unary.Operand;
        Type actualExpressionType = operand.Type;

        MethodCallExpression resultExp = 
            Expression.Call(typeof(Queryable), 
                descending? "OrderByDescending" : "OrderBy",
                new Type[] { typeof(TEntity), actualExpressionType },
                source.Expression, 
                Expression.Lambda(operand, sortExpression.Parameters));
        return source.Provider.CreateQuery<TEntity>(resultExp);
    }
```

The bool descending is to allow for the standard OrderBy and OrderByDescending overloads.  Two major breakthroughs here, at least for me:

1. Getting the Operand out of the expression.
2. Using Expression.Call and Expression.Lambda to create the new expression - this allows me to use an actual "Type" variable, whereas the `Expression<Func<TEntity, T>>` syntax requires you to use a type that's known at compile time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> OrderBy<T>(
       this IEnumerable<T> collection, 
       string columnName
       //, SortDirection direction
)
{
    ParameterExpression param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");   // x
    Expression property = Expression.Property(param, columnName);       // x.ColumnName
    Func<T, object> lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, object>>(        // x => x.ColumnName
            Expression.Convert(property, typeof(object)),
            param)
        .Compile();

    Func<IEnumerable<T>, Func<T, object>, IEnumerable<T>> expression = (c, f) => c.OrderBy(f); // here you can use OrderByDescending basing on SortDirection

    IEnumerable<T> sorted = expression(collection, lambda);
    return sorted;
}
```

Usage:

```
IEnumerable<T> collection = ...
IEnumerable<T> ordered = collection.OrderBy("PropName");
```

---

See [Code Project](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/246361/Handle-GridView-OnSorting-using-LINQ) and [sandbox](http://ideone.com/y9i48d).

Comment: I already have an override that does this - takes a string, finds that property in T, determines the type, and creates a sort Expression.

In this case, though, "PlannedValue" is not a simple property of T.  It's an expression.  It can be converted into Linq easily enough if I know the return value of the expression, but I'm trying to figure out HOW to find the return value of the expression at run time.